# Vscode Extension: DeprecationWarning from unknown source

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

On my vscode extension(https://github.com/razetime/bqn-vscode) I am getting an error which doesn't quite stem from my code:

```
(node:7292) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

The path of the file is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js`, and I don't understand why it is causing this issue.

As a result, the extension is not running, and the main requirement of it - backslash symbol completion is not working. How that works is typing backlash and then a different key to get a required symbol. I'd like to know how to solve this, so I can get that working properly. As of now, it errors with `command 'language-bqn.backslash' not found`

Comment: you can ignore it, it is something the VSC team needs to fix

Comment: Every extension might hit the "command ... not found" issue, but it's not related to that `DeprecationWarning`, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/issues/314#issuecomment-909623401

Comment: So removing the other existing shortcuts should work?

Comment: check EVERY location you need to add the command (3 places) if you forgot one, it happens me to sometime

Comment: I have added in in "keybindings", "contributes.commands", and context.subscriptions.push. Is there any other place